# Can't solve booting issue----irq 7: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)?

Tags: debian, boot, irq

Linux version info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The message always shown on my booting :

```
sudo dmesg | grep "irq 7"
[    2.649135] irq 7: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
```

`irq 7` info on my os:

```
cat /proc/interrupts | head -n 5
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
   0:         35          0          0          0   IO-APIC    2-edge      timer
   1:          0       4226          0          0   IO-APIC    1-edge      i8042
   7:          0          0     100000          0   IO-APIC    7-fasteoi   pinctrl_amd
   8:          0          0          1          0   IO-APIC    8-edge      rtc0
```

My cpu info:

```
lscpu | grep "Model name"
Model name:                      AMD Athlon 3000G with Radeon Vega Graphics
```

It can't solve the issue even to have written irqpoll in the grub.cfg:

```
sudo grep 'irqpoll'  /boot/grub/grub.cfg
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-22-amd64 root=UUID=55aaf5c1-acd2-4bb2-9536-f2900c96d6b2 ro single iommu=pt  irqpoll
```

Comment: Does it affect any of your HW? If it doesn't, simply ignore.